# How to Extract command-line output into a Variable?

Tags: windows, scripting, command-line-interface, environment-variables, logon-scripts

As part of a task that I am working on for a customer, I need to make some modifications to the enterprise logon script.  Windows command-line is definitely not my area of expertise, but I am doing OK with most it.  However, I have one problem that I cannot figure out how to do.

Basically, I need to get the IP address of the machines default gateway into an environment variable (for later use in the script).  I know that it exists in the output of both `ipconfig` and of `tracert`, and I know how to find the exact line in their output that I need, but I cannot figure out how to get beyond that.

For example, the following command produces output like this:

```
>ipconfig|Find "Default Gateway"|Findstr/N "."|Findstr/B "1:"

 1:   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 199.99.9.1
```

But now I need to somehow extract only the IP address out of this text line and then assign it to an environment variable.  So, how can I do that from a Windows command-line?  (Windows XP and higher).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for /f` is your friend.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %A in (`ipconfig ^| Find "Default Gateway" ^| Findstr/N "." ^| Findstr/B "1:"`) do @if not defined MYVAR set MYVAR=%~C
```

...might do the trick.

**Edit:** changed the code block to read the *third* value not the second, and needed to escape the pipes.

You *could* also shorten to:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %A in (`ipconfig ^| Find "Default Gateway" ^| Findstr/N "."`) do @if not defined MYVAR set MYVAR=%~C
```

...as, *technically*, the second `findstr` (where you limit to the first result) is actually handled by the `if not defined`

Comment: OK, that's completely new to me.  I'll check it out ...

Comment: Wow, that works great.  But it is coming back with some leading spaces.  Is there any convenient way to trim them off?

Comment: Ironically, another `for /f` with "delims= " would do it - for /f "usebackq delims= " %A in (`echo %MYVAR%`) do @set MYVAR=%A

Comment: Or, possibly, `SET MYVAR=%MYVAR: =%` (in theory, replace spaces in MYVAR with nothing -- YMMV)

Comment: Ever notice that hardly anyone uses For/if and environment variables anymore ?
Tons of expert advice across the web from people insisting you type out hard paths "c:\program files" and just change it for your system instead of just %programfiles% or others. Jim, are you and old hand or just learned from old wizards ? I detect experience in your Fu

Comment: Old enough but, really, everything I learned about batch I learned from http://robvanderwoude.com (and maybe http://ss64.com)

Comment: Yep, I just now figured out that string substitution (Set A=%A: =%) would work.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 - epic batch is epic. I never could get the syntax of `for` right - it once cost me a job interview for a dream job.